# Como faço para pegar id de uma categoria usando o retorno do nome da categoria da função Wordpress single_cat_title();

Tags: php, wordpress

Amigos tenho um menu com os seguintes links da Categorias **Produtos** e **Notícias** quero que ao clicar em qualquer um dos links e minha página **category.php** retorne somente os posts da categoria a que foi clicada.

Tenho em minha página **single_cat_title();** que retorna o nome da categoria, gostaria de saber como posso pegar o ID desta categoria para assim usar no array $args

$args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'category'=>**CODIGO_CATEGORIA**, 'showposts'=>3);

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
        $args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'category'=>single_cat_title(), 'showposts'=>3);
        $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
        if($my_posts) : foreach($my_posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
     ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(false, array('class'=>'img-responsive img-post-blog')); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

     <?php
        endforeach;
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema.

```
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$categoriaID = get_cat_ID($page_object->cat_name);
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'category' => $categoriaID, 'showposts' => 3);
```

Retornei com resposta pois isto pode ajudar.